# Image Gallery, Open Source, that can be fully Integrated into our existing Website

Tags: php, html, web-applications, content-management-system

Can anyone help me find a suitable Open Source Image Gallery.  My main problem seems to be that I am looking for something which can be Fully Integrated into our existing website rather than having to make our site look like the image gallery template.

Thank,

Comment: your tag includes CMS. Are you using a CMS currently? Do you need to display a gallery of photos, or provide a full-featured multi-user upload & download experience?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out gallery:

http://gallery.menalto.com/

I don't know if this is too 'templated' for your needs, but it's open source, and allows for custom module development, so changing the appearance shouldn't be too challenging.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion user470714, unfortunately I have looked at that and the advise I read from the 'Gallery' community is that full integration is not possible.  Only has the ability to create a similar Theme to make it look the same.